# xcode beta bridgeToObjectiveC alternative?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am currently making a calculator app and I need to use the bridgeToObjectiveC code but that is no longer available in the current beta version of xcode 6. This is the code I need to write:

```
 @IBAction func btnAdditionCalculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstNumber = txtAdditionFirst.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue
    let secondNumber = txtAdditionSecond.text.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue
    let answer = firstNumber + secondNumber

    var answerFormat: NSString = NSString(format: "%0.0f", answer)

    labelAdditionAnswer.text = " \(answerFormat)"

}
```

I know I need to use NSString and I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func btnAdditionCalculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstNumber = (txtAdditionFirst.text as NSString).floatValue
    let secondNumber = (txtAdditionSecond.text as NSString).floatValue

    let answer = firstNumber + secondNumber

    var answerFormat: NSString = NSString(format: "%0.0f", answer)

    labelAdditionAnswer.text = " \(answerFormat)"

}
```

Thanks for all your help

edit 8/15

When I run the code on the iOS simulator, the app loads and I am able to put numbers into the number 1 and number 2 slot, however when I press calculate xcode highlights the let firstNumber line and says Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and this is the error message I get:

```
2014-08-15 16:14:53.019 Innovative Calculator p1[578:8032] Can't find keyplane that                          supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
2014-08-15 16:14:55.425 Innovative Calculator p1[578:8032] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 1425143906_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Comment: Is `txtAdditionFirst` an `IBOutlet`? Is it definitely connected?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is halting on `let firstNumber = ...` with a nil optional conversion, it means you are incorrectly assuming that either `txtAdditionFirst` or `textAdditionFirst.text` is not nil.  UITextField makes assurances that `.text` is never nil so the best bet is that you failed to wire up `txtAdditionFirst` in Interface Builder.

You can verify this by checking the variable definition to see it it is filled in or set a breakpoint above the line and see if it is nil.

**If** you have a valid reason for the variable to be nil, you have a couple options for doing this:

```
// The long way (mutable)
var firstNumber:Float = 0
if let value = textField?.text {
    firstNumber = (value as NSString).floatValue
}

// The short way (not mutable)
let firstNumber = (textField?.text? as NSString?)?.floatValue ?? 0.0
```

The first way sets the number to zero initially then uses optional chaining to test if textField and textField.text are not nil.  The second way uses optional chaining the whole way to get an optional float value, then unwraps it if not nil or falls back to 0.